# Android Keep view's bottom fixed while translating it's Y

Tags: android, android-animation, android-gridview, android-toolbar

I have a  view that fill my screen, i'm animating its Y so the top of it going hidden, **BUT** i need it's button keep it's position.

the animation code:

```
mainLayout.animate().translationY(-toolbar.getBottom()).setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator()).start();
```

Before Scrolling:

[image]

After Scrolling:

[image]

**NOTE:**

1) i'm doing this because i need to hide toolbar on scroll.

2) i tried other method for hiding toolbar include animating toolbar height, margin, padding, BUT they are laggy as hell.

3) i tried to translate the toolbar but it's below layout keep their position and won't move up.

**UPDATE 1:**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/home_drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    tools:context=".HomeActivity"
    android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    >

    <!-- main view -->
    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/tansparent"
        android:id="@+id/home_main_layout"
        tools:context=".HomeActivity">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                           android:id="@+id/home_toolbar"
                                           android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                           android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                                           android:background="@color/category_activity_topbar_background"
                                           app:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"
                                           android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

        <com.viewpagerindicator.TabPageIndicator
            android:id="@+id/tab_indicator"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/tab_height"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/home_toolbar"/>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/home_pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/tab_indicator"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/addBookButton"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/add_button_width_height"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/add_button_width_height"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/add_button"
            android:background="@drawable/circles_background"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/add_button_margin_bottom"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/add_button_margin_right"
            android:onClick="importNewBooksButtonMethod"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- drawer -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/settingDrawer"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/setting_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:clickable="true">
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: paste your layout XML

Comment: @GauravPolekar , posted, please look at the **Update 1**

Comment: Ok so what I understood is that its ok becouse of 
*android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"*

So what I suggest you to use FrameLayout as a parent and put all code in that and then place imagebutton over that

Answer (score 1):

ok, i animated the whole view and after that i set margin for the view to a negative value. toolbar getting hide and everything works smooth an fine.

```
homeMainLayout.animate().translationY(-toolbar.getBottom()).setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator()).withEndAction(new Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    DrawerLayout.LayoutParams params = (DrawerLayout.LayoutParams) homeMainLayout.getLayoutParams();
                    params.bottomMargin = -toolbarHeight;
                    homeMainLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
                }
            }).start();
```